# Module not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm learning Javascript and Node and I am trying to create a module that extends String. First I got the error require is not defined so I started using requireJS. Then I got this error `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied` so I moved `project.html` into the same folder as my `.js` files. Now I am getting module not defined in `require.js` and I can't seem to figure out why. I've read through some other posts but I didn't find a solution. My file structure looks like this

> - strip/
>
>   - scripts/
>   - main.js
>   - require.js
>   - project.html
>   - helper/
>
>     - extendString.js

**main.js**

```
define(function(require, exports, module){
  var StringHelperModule = require("helper/extendString.js");
  StringHelperModule.extendString(String);

  var tmp = 'Hello World'.strip(' ');
  document.write(tmp);
  //Outputs: HelloWorld
});
```

**extendString.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function extendString(String){
  String.prototype.strip = function (delimiter) {
    return this.replace(delimiter, '');
  };
};
```

**project.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script data-main='main' src='require.js'></script>
   </head>
</html>
```

**require.js**

```
(function () {
    // Separate function to avoid eval pollution, same with arguments use.
    function exec() {
        eval(arguments[0]); //This is line the error points to
    }

    require.load = function (context, moduleName, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                exec(xhr.responseText);

                //Support anonymous modules.
                context.completeLoad(moduleName);
            }
        };
    };
}());
```

I'm also getting not well-formed before it says module not defined if that has anything to do with this

Comment: Did you try: `require("./helper/extendString.js");`? (note the dot at the beginning)

Comment: @leo.fcx Yes and it didn't help. I just found a common error on the requirejs site that might be my problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. [error](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#defineerror)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mixing module formats here, your module looks more like CommonJS, than AMD format.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  'use strict';

  module.exports = function extendString () {
    String.prototype.strip = function (delimiter) {
      return this.replace(delimiter, '');
    };
  };
});
```

Then, in your main.js, you should use require(), instead of define().
Also, note, that you don't need to pass String to function, it's global.

```
require(
  ['path/to/extendString'],
    function (extendString) {
      extendString(); // add the methods to String.prototype
      console.log('Hello awesome world!'.strip(' '));
    }
);
```

That should work.

Comment: That got rid of the module error. Now I just need to figure out why it is saying `strip` is not a function. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe because you should call extendString() before trying to access the newly added methods. Or you can add the methods right in define, not inside module.exports.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. Do you mind adding this to your answer under use it? `extendString();` and then `document.write('Hello World'.strip(' '));` It would make a really nice and complete answer