# React js SyntaxError Occurs in Node Modules webpack chokidar.js 'return' outside of function (4:2)

Tags: reactjs, chokidar

I am facing this issue from last day.. **No solution** for this error Complete *error log* is mentioned below

```
var v3Err;
try {
    module.exports = require("chokidar");
    return;
} catch(e) {
    v3Err = e;
}
```

Error occurs in 'return' outside of function (4:2)

**SyntaxError: E:\test\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js: 'return' outside of function (4:2)**

at Object._raise (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\error.js:60:45)
at Object.raiseWithData (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\error.js:55:17)
at Object.raise (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\error.js:39:17)
at Object.parseReturnStatement (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:563:12)
at Object.parseStatementContent (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:197:21)
at Object.parseStatement (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:151:17)
at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:873:25)
at Object.parseBlockBody (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:843:10)
at Object.parseBlock (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:813:10)
at Object.parseStatementContent (E:\test\node_modules@babel\parser\src\parser\statement.js:218:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forbes-me@1.0.0 start: `pawjs --no-cache --config=./pawconfig.json --env=development start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forbes-me@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\glowlogix\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-17T09_19_41_742Z-debug.log

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to wrap `module.exports` in a try catch. If it's cos you think `module` might not be defined, you might be mixing up module types. Check out this post for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659956/module-not-defined

Answer (score 28):

I was facing the same problem in my project. An autocomplete (due to a typo) automatically added an import to my file. When i removed it my problem was solved. So i advice you to check your modules for unnecessary imports.

[example of my auto added import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYaAL.png)

Answer (score 8):

I faced a similar issue in my code, an unwanted autocmplete addded and unnecessary import in my code.

```
import { IgnorePlugin } from 'webpack';
```

Removed this import and it got back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

unwanted import is added for me. removed and it worked.

- import { LoaderOptionsPlugin } from 'webpack';

Answer (score 0):

***Uwanted Imports of modules from webpack*** in any of the components caused me the error,search through every files to check if there is any unwanted imports which might have crawled in due to auto-type